# How to access the data sent via Jquery.getJSON from the server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, express

I have the following `$.getJSON` request on the client side:

```
$.getJSON('/video/getToken', {classroomId: roomName}, cb);
```

On the server side:

```
router.route('/video/getToken')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

The `console.log` is returning an empty object. Shouldn't the output be
`{classroomId: roomName}`?

Comment: It is available in `cb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a GET request, so there is no request body, instead you need to access the `req.query`:

**Express 4.***

```
router.route('/video/getToken')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        console.log( req.query.classroomId );
    });
```

**Express 3.***

```
router.route('/video/getToken')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        console.log( req.query("classroomId") );
    });
```